# angularjs directive - transclude non working as expected

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I'm writing a submenu directive, but I'm unable to use transclude properly for some reason. I've read and watched some videos, but it still doesn't work on my app and I can't figure out why.

Here's how I call the directive:

```
<my-submenu>
  <div ng-click="test()">Test</div>
  <div ng-click="test2()">Test 2</div>
  <div ng-click="test3(id, type)">Test 3</div>
  <div ui-sref="test ({id: id})">Test 4</div> 
</my-submenu>
```

and the directive js is:

```
  {
    link: linkFunction,
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: './directives/submenu.tpl.html'
  }
```

and the directive template is:

```
<div>
    <!-- Menu Icon -->
    <div class="icon ion-plus"></div>
    <!-- Menu -->
    <div>
        <div ng-transclude></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I though that using transclude and telling the directive template where to transclude, I should be able to add content to the directive template as well as content where I call if from my parent, and have it compiled togheter, but it is not doing that.

The resulting compiled code is the following:

```
<my-submenu>
 <div>
  <div ng-click="test()">Test</li>
  <div ng-click="test2()">Test 2</li>
  <div ng-click="test3(id, type)">Test 3</li>
  <div ui-sref="test ({id: id})">Test 4</li>
 </ul>
</my-submenu>
```

and as you can see, the Icon before the transclude is gone and not displayed at all. Why?

What am I doing wrong with the transclude? thanks

Comment: Did you try with replace:false ?

Comment: yes and I have the same result

Comment: You're using transclude correctly, something else must be causing this.

Comment: Apparently, the problem was in the order of the link function. I was calling it after and that didn't work. I moved the link function above the object and now it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this with the same way as your and it works properly..

My directive:

```
myApp.directive('toolbarItem', function() {
return {
    transclude:true,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    },
    templateUrl:'/toolbarItem.html'
}
```

});

And my template:

```
<div class="item" ng-transclude></div>
```